# Uniform bound for rare events

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Consider a family $F$ of subsets of a probability space $\Omega$. Assume that $F$ has bounded VC dimension and that the measure of each subset in $F$ is at least $\epsilon$.

Drawing $n$ iid points from $\Omega$, can we find a good lower bound on the probability that all subsets in $F$ contain at least a point?

I tried using the uniform CLT (VC inequality), but it seems suboptimal in the regime where the expected number of points in each subset is small.

Answer (score 1):

The worst-case scenario is when elements of $F$ are disjoint.  Let $k$ be the number of elements of $F$.  Then, using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174674/if-n-balls-are-thrown-into-k-bins-what-is-the-probability-that-every-bin-gets-a) with Stirling numbers, the probability that all those elements are occupied is

$$\sum_i {\binom ni} (k\epsilon)^i  (1-k\epsilon)^{n-i}
\left\{
\begin{array}& i \\ k \end{array}
\right\} k!/k^i$$

$$=k!\sum_i {\binom ni}
\left\{
\begin{array}& i \\ k \end{array}
\right\}
\epsilon^i  (1-k\epsilon)^{n-i}
$$

If $\epsilon$ is small in the sense that $n\epsilon<k$, then it may be enough to use the lower bound from the $i=k$ term:
$$\epsilon^k (1-k\epsilon)^{n-k}n! /(n-k)!
$$